# order-preserving function on a well-ordered set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a well-ordered set $(A,≤)$ and a function $f:A\to A$ that is one to one and also $f$ preserves the order (for every $a,b\in A,$ if $a\le b$ then $f(a)\le f(b).$)
I need to prove that $a\le f(a).$
I have a problem when $A$ is infinite. When A is finite I proved that $f$ is also surjective  and $f(a)=a.$ When $A$ is infinite  I'm really stuck and I don't know what to do and how to prove it.

Comment: i know that when A is infinte this is wrong . i just dont know how to proof that a≤f(a) and not the opposite .  ( i know that one of them must be in the relation because this is a linnear relation . )

Comment: you right .  my bad . didnt translate it well

Comment: of course. thanks

Comment: i can say that f(f(a))<f(a) but still i dont have contradiction .. maybe it will work if i will take a as a minimum ? or maybe i just didnt get it yet.

Answer (score 6):

Assume for a contradiction that $f(a)\lt a$ for some $a\in A.$ In other words, the set $S=\{x\in A:f(x)\lt x\}$ is nonempty. Since $(A,\le)$ is well-ordered, the set $S$ has a least element call it $a.$

Since $f$ is order-preserving and one-to-one, from $f(a)\lt a$ it follows that $f(f(a))\lt f(a),$ whence $f(a)\in S.$ Since $f(a)\lt a,$ this contradicts the fact that $a$ is the *least* element of $S.$